# Different style in Home and Category Pages

Tags: theme, css, category-products

After I installed the Product Units and Quantities Extension, my Category Page just got a different "style". I tried to copy the `catalog/category/view.phtml` from a older backup but it doesn't changed anything. Another thing that is happening is that the AJAX Cart stopped working in category pages. It just redirect to `/cart`.

Beautiful Home Page:

[image]

Ugly Category Page:

[image]

Anyone knows how to fix it?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I recommend trying is to temporarily deactivate the extension to see if it returns to the correct layout. You can deactivate a module via the `app/etc/modules/[ModuleName].xml` file. If that does fix the problem, it relegates the problem to that specific extension.

If it is the extension, there is probably some layout XML that is causing the problem by rendering their template instead of the default `catalog/category/view.phtml`. That may not be the only template that was impacted.

I suggest that you reach out to their support if you confirm that it is an issue with their layouts.